# Compute the explicit formula of a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The recursive formula is ${T_{n + 1}} = \frac{b}{{n + b}} + \frac{{a + b + n}}{{n + b}}{T_n}$ and $T_1=1$. The result is $T_n=\frac{b}{a}\frac{{{{(b + a)}_n}}}{{{{(b)}_n}}} - \frac{b}{a}$ where ${(x)_n}$ denotes ${(x)_n} = (x)(x + 1)...(x + n - 1)$. I don't want to use induction to verify the result. Hope someone can help with a non-induction proof.

**Based on David's hint I have derived the explicit formula**. As in his hint, the trick is to let $Q_n=T_n-T_{n-1}$, thus $Q_{n}=\frac{(a+b+n-2)}{(b+n-1)}Q_{n-1}$. Simply expand it and we will get $Q_n=\frac{(a+b)_n}{(b)_n}\times\frac{b}{a+b+n-1}=T_n-T_{n-1}$. Plug this result into the original recursion ${T_{n}} = \frac{b}{{n + b - 1}} + \frac{{a + b + n - 1}}{{n + b - 1}}{T_{n-1}}$ and we will arrive at the solution.

Comment: Try taking the z-transform of both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following procedure simplifies the problem. maybe you can use this hint?

clearing fractions:
$$
(n+b)T_{n+1} = b + (n+a+b)T_n
$$
so:
$$
(n-1+b)T_n = b + (n-1+a+b)T_{n-1}
$$
subtracting
$$
(n+b)(T_{n+1}-T_n) +T_n = (n+a+b)(T_n-T_{n-1}) +T_{n-1}
$$
or, setting $Q_n=T_n-T_{n-1}$
$$
(b+n)Q_{n+1} = (a+b+n-1)Q_n
$$
we can now multiply these equations for $n,n-1,....$

Comment: Thank you! I have derived the explicit formula based on your hint!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to prove the result, without induction, although honestly it'll look pretty similar. Substitute your solution into the original recurrence relation, on both sides. If they equal each other, the recurrence solution is correct. I believe this is different from proof by induction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but what I actually want is to solve the problem, not to verify the result.

Comment: @Tony don't you already have the solution? In which case verifying the result, is proving the result.